# Terminal on Mac stopped launching after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, bash, zsh

It was so nice so far working with `bash` until my laptop got upgraded to Catalina and now Terminal does not launch at all.

Any hints? I am not sure if it is related to `zsh` or what; I am a `bash` guy.

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7 and Terminal 2.10.433

I launch Terminal from Spotlight and it shows the first line and when I hit enter it says [Process completed].

```
Last login: Thu Dec 15 09:17:52 on ttys000

[Process completed]
```

In **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups**, right-click user to get **Advance Options**, I see `/bin/bash`, and even if I chose another `/sh` or `/zsh` my terminal does not start and gives the above message.

Answer (score 3):

With the Terminal still open, go to Settings (in the Terminal menu) and set the command to be run to `/bin/bash --noprofile`.

[image]

Then open a new Terminal window with <kbd>Cmd-N</kbd> and review your .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc for any errors.